# Can i JSON serialize a object which contains a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I've run into a issue when using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addToBasketView) as it seems not to  like tha list that i pass into it - until i passed in the list it was working fine - are you not able to pass a list?

Here is my code:

controller:

```
//We need a list of Automation scripts - this was in Apollo but now we need to pass it in teh message
           var automationList = AutomationHelper(retailerId, productId);

 var addToBasketView = new AddToBasketView
            {
                Url = retailerProduct.DeepLink,
                Password = (password),
                Username = (username),
                RetailerProductJson = new RetailerProductJson(retailerProduct),
                WidgetImpressionId = id,
                Quantity = qty,
                MessageId = messageId,
                AutomationList = automationList
            };


            // now turn it into a string
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addToBasketView);
```

Addtobasketview.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WidgetData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the view that we will give to the AddToBasketForm
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class AddToBasketView
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// The Username for the retailer
        /// </summary>
        public String Username { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The password for the retailer
        /// </summary>
        public String Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The URl of the thing they want added to the site
        /// </summary>
        public String Url { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The retailer product selected - from this I can get the retailer and the product.
        /// </summary>
        public RetailerProductJson RetailerProductJson { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The widget impression id so that we can attach to the addTobaskets table for recording purposes
        /// </summary>
        public int WidgetImpressionId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// set the quantity
        /// </summary>
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The MessageId this is so we can identify it when waiting for a response
        /// </summary>
        public String MessageId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Automation script list
        /// </summary>
        public List<AutomationStepScript> AutomationList { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Edit:**
AutomationStepScript.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WidgetData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the class created by Linq To SQL, so that we can control in our models section the validity of the data
    /// </summary>
    [MetadataType(typeof(AuotmationStepScriptValidation))]
    public partial class AutomationStepScript
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Override the to string so that we can use in the delete method to capture details of this record before it is deleted
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
           return string.Format("AutomationStepScript Id = {0}, AutomationStepId = {1}, Sort Order = {2}, Description = {3}, Script = {4}, Evaluate = {5}", Id,AutomationStepId,SortOrder,Description,Script,Evaluate);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to validate my AuotmationStepScript
    /// </summary>
    public class AuotmationStepScriptValidation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// AutomationId
        /// </summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "AutomationStepId is a required field")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "AutomationStepId must be valid")]
        public int AutomationStepId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display SortOrder
        /// </summary>
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "SortOrder must be valid")]
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description 
        /// </summary>
        [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Description maximum length is 256", MinimumLength = 1)]
        public String Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Script
        /// </summary>
        [AllowHtml]
        [StringLength(8000, ErrorMessage = "Script maximum length is 8000")]
        public String Script { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Evaluate
        /// </summary>
        public int Evaluate { get; set; }
    }


}
```

AutomationHelper (called in teh controller to get the list:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// The helper function to fetch the data so that we can get the scripts for each step for this automation (which we will find from the localParams)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="retailerId"> </param>
        /// <param name="productId"> </param>
        /// <returns>WE return a List of AutomationStepScripts, this object will be selected further with Lambda expression"></returns>
        public List<AutomationStepScript> AutomationHelper(int retailerId, int productId)
        {
            List<AutomationStepScript> automationStepScripts = null;
            var automationStepScriptRepository = new AutomationStepScriptRepository();
            var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
            var retailerCategoryRepository = new RetailerCategoryRepository();
            var product = productRepository.GetProduct(productId);
            var categoryId = product.CategoryId;
            var retailerCategory = retailerCategoryRepository.GetRetailerCategoryByRetailerCategory(retailerId, categoryId);

            // DO we have a retailer category?
            if (retailerCategory != null)
            {
                // Yes, without a valid retailer category we cannot possibly find the automation
                // Now here we have the RetailerCategory. The next question is Does this RetailerCategory HAVE an automation set up for it
                if (retailerCategory.AutomationId != null)
                {
                    // Yes, we have an automation. So lets get all of the Scripts for all of the steps for this automation
                    // Get All scripts for all steps for this automation.
                    automationStepScripts = automationStepScriptRepository.GetAllAutomationStepScriptsForAutomation((int)retailerCategory.AutomationId).ToList();
                }
            }
            return automationStepScripts;
        }
```

I am serializinf it as it bacomes teh body of a message which i am using in SQS which i then use later.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show an example of what the JSON looks like with the list? Also, out of curiosity have you marked `AutomationStepScript` as `Serializable`?

Comment: You certainly can serialize lists, is it the List<AutomationStepScript> that is not serializing? If so, it might help if you posted that class definition too.

Comment: @Stony please see my edits for more code

Comment: I've not tried serializing the classes generated by Entity Framework before, are you sure that they can be? Have you tried creating an instance of one manually and seeing if that can be serialized? FWIW, the scenarios where I have been serializing generic lists have all been with simple POCO classes.

Comment: no i m not certain may have to seperate it out